# Xcode: error: failed to launch with duplicated target. Original target runs fine in Xcode/gdb

Tags: ios, xcode, gdb, target, lldb

I have an app that I want to be able to build two different versions.  One a "test" version that hits test databases, populates a test analytics backend, etc, and then the "live" version  which its the production database and analytics backend.

So I duplicated my target, made appropriate changes, and I can build both, and both get installed on the phone, and I can run both manually on the phone.  However, when I try to run it in Xcode on the device in order to debug with gdb or lldb (same error happens with both), the original target runs fine.  However, the duplicated target (the "test" one) gives an error when running on the device (both run fine in the simulator, the problem is only running on the device)

lldb gives:  [APPNAME] is the overall app name -- the test version has product set to [APPNAME]Test

error: failed to launch '/Users/chad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[PROJNAME]-ezbuaazlwmgdwydjykcufhicaspu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[APPNAME]Test.app/[APPNAME]Test'

gdb basically gives a dialog box that says that the same path cannot be found.

However, that path actually DOES exist.  If I cut and past the path from the Xcode debugger window and go to Terminal and type % ls -a '/Users/chad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[PROJNAME]-ezbuaazlwmgdwydjykcufhicaspu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[APPNAME]Test.app/[APPNAME]Test'

it finds it just fine.  I can also click in Xcode in the file list under the Products folder and click on [APPNAME]Test.app and choose in the contextual menu to "Show in Finder" and it finds it just fine.

AND the app does get copied to the phone and it shows up in the organizer and I can manually launch the app and it runs on the device.  It just won't auto launch in Xcode on the device for the copied target, while the original target runs just fine in Xcode.

I'd appreciate any insight into this.  This is my first real time playing with multiple targets on an iPhone project I created (versus working on a team on a project someone else created).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you know.  Xcode crashed (for some totally other reason when I was doing something different unrelated to this) and now both targets will launch and run from Xcode.  So I guess the solution is to quit Xcode after duplicating a target if you have problems with the target launching from Xcode.